# How can i get the actual file in an XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

How can i get the actual file in an XMLHttpRequest?
Using evt.target.files returns a fileList object, and I am not able to grab the actual file on the php end, in order to save on server.

Below is the code, and I have attached  an image showing the responseText returned from the php code `print_r($_POST);`

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {

  reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    // Ensure that the progress bar displays 100% at the end.
    progress.style.width = '100%';
    progress.textContent = '100%';
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('progress_bar').className='';", 2000);


    ///////////THE JSON/////////////to encase file in JSON object
    var sendFile = function(url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
      var xhr = typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined' ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      xhr.open('post', url, true);

      //XHR progress tracking
      xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
        //var native_progress = document.getElementById("native_progress");
        //alert('in native_progress function');
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
          var complete = (event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0);
          native_progress.value = native_progress.innerHTML = complete;
        }
      };

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var status;
        var data;
        // https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) { // `DONE`
          status = xhr.status;
          if (status == 200) {
            //data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            data = xhr.responseText;
            successHandler && successHandler(data);
          } else {
            errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
          }
        }
      };

      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', evt.target.files[0]);
      //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/gorm-data");
      //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.send(formData);
    };

    sendFile('/ePub_Reader/temp_upload/save.php', function(data) {
      alert('Response Text: ' + data);
    }, function(status) {
      alert('Something went wrong.');
    });
    ///////////THE JSON - end/////////////

    // Read in the image file as a binary string.
    //reader.readAsBinaryString(evt.target.files[0]);
    reader.readAsDataURL(evt.target.files[0]);
  }

}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

[image: Alert Showing php responseText generated by <code>print_r($_POST);</code>]

Answer (score 0):

You append a single file to a FormData object not a FileList

```
formData.append('file', evt.target.files[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks Musa. But i have changed code many times and mistakenly placed `evt.target.files` without the `[0]` in my post. I iterate through the array to pick the `[i]` item.\n Now to be clear, i have tested the following, `var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', evt.target.files[0]);
  alert(evt.target.files[0]['size']);
  alert(evt.target.files[0]);`, the size gives '663732 bytes', the second alert gives '[object file]', but when i return `print_r($_POST['file']);` i get '[object filelist]', and `fwrite($name_handle, $_POST['file']);` saves a 'corrupted' file of only 17byte.

Comment: File information is stored in `$_FILES` not `$_POST`

Comment: Good. Using `$_FILES['file']` if get an array responseText `Array
(
    [name] => Saved_Book.epub
    [type] => application/epub+zip
    [tmp_name] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpoUpcZ6
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 663732
)`. And the `fwrite()` function stores a "corrupt" file of 0bytes.

Comment: I am now thinking to `fopen()` the file from the temporary location as shown in the `tmp_name` key.